# Django Rest framework keeps returning error on nested relationship

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Staring at my code for quite a while and I keep running into the same error. Funny thing is that I made a similar set of serializers for another part of my model and those work fine.

This is the error that I keep getting:

> AttributeError at /onderhoudapi/conditiedeel/.json Got AttributeError
>   when attempting to get a value for field `gebreken` on serializer
>   `ConditiedeelSerializer`. The serializer field might be named
>   incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Conditiedeel`
>   instance. Original exception text was: 'Conditiedeel' object has no
>   attribute 'gebreken'.

serializers.py

```
class GebrekSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Gebrek
        fields = ('naam', 'get_type', 'get_omvang_waarde', 'get_intensiteit_waarde', 'get_ernst_waarde')


class ConditiedeelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    gebreken = GebrekSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Conditiedeel
        fields = ('deel', 'conditiescore', 'gebreken', )
```

models.py

```
class Conditiedeel(models.Model):
    deel = models.OneToOneField(Deel, null=True, blank=True)
    conditiegroep = models.ForeignKey(Conditiegroep)
    conditiescore = models.IntegerField(choices=CONDITIE_KEUZES)

    #some class methods here


class Gebrek(models.Model):
    naam = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    omvang = models.IntegerField(choices=OMVANG_KEUZES)
    intensiteit = models.IntegerField(choices=INTENSITEIT_KEUZES)
    conditiedeel = models.ForeignKey(Conditiedeel)
    nengebrek = models.ForeignKey(Nengebrek)

    #class methods here
```

As you can see, the `Gebrek` class has a foreign relationship to the Conditiedeel class. That should mean I can use a nested relationship like [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/). I think I followed the example closely, yet I cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem here is that `Conditiedeel` model has not an attribute called `gebreken`, remember that you are trying to get backwards relationship objects, so you need to use `gebreken_set` as field as django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) says. So your serializer should be

```
class ConditiedeelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    gebrek_set = GebrekSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Conditiedeel
        fields = ('deel', 'conditiescore', 'gebrek_set', )
```

Comment: That actually works. Was confused because the docs use "tracks" rather than "track_set"..

Comment: Please update your answer from "gebreken_set" to "gebrek_set". That way I can also upvote it again.

Comment: I was very much convinced that your answer would not solve the issue. Honestly I still do not quite understand why it worked or rather why my previous solution dod not work. I am well aware of the `_set` pattern in the normal Django database api, but the rest-framework doen not seem top rely on it. Both the docs and my previous code do not rely on _set for foreign keys.

Comment: @RoyPrins Read here [Reverse relations](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/) they mention _set prefix to get backwards relationship that is your case.