# Django Rest Framework - Nested Serialization not working as expected

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

While using Django-REST-Framework, I am not able to display selected fields in a nested serialized object.

I am correctly able to serialize the entirety of the `Address` model, but I want only a few fields from `Address`, nested in my serialized `Outlet`. There is a

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `outlet_address` on serializer `OutletSerializer`.
>   The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Outlet` instance.
>   Original exception text was: 'Outlet' object has no attribute 'outlet_address'.

**api_v1/models.py**

```
class Address(models.Model):
    building = models.CharField(_("shop number, floor & building"), max_length=128)
    street = models.CharField(_("street"), max_length=128, blank=True)
    area = models.ManyToManyField(Area, related_name='address')
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, related_name='address')
    pin_code = models.CharField(_("PIN code"), max_length=6, default="")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.building + " " + self.street + " ..."


class Outlet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    chain = models.ForeignKey(Chain, related_name='outlet', blank=True, null=True)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.OneToOneField(Address, related_name='outlet_address')
    thumbnail = AjaxImageField(upload_to='thumbnails',
                               max_height=200,  #optional
                               max_width=200,  # optional
                               crop=True)  # optional
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(_('date created'), default=timezone.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

**api_v1/serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from api_v1.models import Outlet, Address

class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #address_area = AreaSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ('building', 'street',)
        depth = 3


class OutletSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    outlet_address = AddressSerializer(many=False)
    #area = serializers.CharField(source='address.area') #multiple levels of nesting?

    class Meta:
        model = Outlet
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'thumbnail', 'outlet_address')
        # fields = ('id', 'name', 'thumbnail', 'address') # this works
        depth = 3
```

At this point, it is unable to find the outlet_address attribute in the Outlet model while I expect it should be able to in the serializer.

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field
>   `outlet_address` on serializer `OutletSerializer`. The serializer
>   field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on
>   the `Outlet` instance. Original exception text was: 'Outlet' object
>   has no attribute 'outlet_address'.

As described on other answers, I have tried:

1. adding `many=` to the ModelSerializer
2. adding `related_name=` to all Models

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from api_v1.models import Outlet, Address

class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ('building', 'street',)
        depth = 3


class OutletSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    address = AddressSerializer(many=False) # make it address, not outlet_address

    class Meta:
        model = Outlet
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'thumbnail', 'address') # make this address as well, not outlet_address
        depth = 3
```

The reason I would make the changes above is because the Outlet model does not have an attribute called "outlet_address", it has an attribute called "address".

See here for a similar issue: [Django Rest framework keeps returning error on nested relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28532420/django-rest-framework-keeps-returning-error-on-nested-relationship)

Comment: I did see the linked article earlier, but it was for backward relationships. Your answer works perfectly and also now I understand DRF magic a bit better. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Additionally to the other answers, I would like to add the following in case somebody lands here too.

The nested serialization requires the field name to be in the model fields in order to work.

In case that we need a [reverse relation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#reverse-relations), then obviously there will be no such field in the model fields.

For example, with the particular models in the question, this would happen if we needed to reference all outlets in the address serializer.

Therefore we need to: (a) Either specify a `related_name` to the foreign key of the other model. This is where we would use `outlet_address`, as this is the related name of address field in outlet model.

Or (b) if no related name then use the default Django name, appending `_set` to the model name (eg `outlet_set`.

Comment: Very helpful @Wtower. I send my gratitude.

Answer (score 3):

Model Outlet has an "address" field, not an outlet_address. I would advise to set your serializer like this:

```python
class OutletSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    address = AddressSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Outlet
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'thumbnail', 'address')
        depth = 2
```